# Why Does My Motivation Fluctuate So Much?

Tags: motivation

I'm motivated to do a lot of stuff when I get up from the PC to go to the toilet.

But once I sit back down at the PC, all the motivation evaporates.

Explanation and how to fix it?

How to psych myself up?

Comment: Interesting. When I watched "Dexter's Laboratory" going in late 90s I remember episode where Dexter in bathroom sat on a toilet and said how it helps him to think better. I found myself in a similar situation but it's not just toilet. It can be kitchen, a walk outside etc. Suddenly my mind gets clear and I get a bird's eye view of all things that I wanted to accomplish for the day. That boring or "hard" task that I was slowly trying to complete seems not as hard.